# Blender Unwanted Bouncy Physics

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

So I have made a wall out of bricks with rigid body, with Convex Hull enabled on every brick, and what I want is to have it collapsing into a big pile of bricks. It is sort of working except, that the bricks just can't stop bouncing, even though there is no external force acting on them. They just can't stay in one place. Bouncing is set to 0, Friction is beyond imaginable, it is technically maxed. Raising the Friction from 1 to that almost infinite number did help a lot, but didn't solve the issue fully.
I tried every possible setup combination in the Rigid Body settings, but it is still not working properly.

Also, I have a second question, regarding if I am able to bake rigid body physics or not?

Download: https://mega.nz/#!otBDWZDI!YvbpjFBP0dlo_eLxB57QCEpd3g2M9oJtBZ_B0W-Mvv0
Alternative Download: [image]

(Just run the simulation and watch the damaged building)

Comment: Please use [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload blend files.

Comment: I think I just did, but what is the point of over complicating it? I mean, I have no idea, if it has been added to the thread or not. I have no idea if it is even visible for you or not. The Mega link is just a copy-paste solution, really.

Comment: You need to copy the link gived after upload and copy it to the question.. Use [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/88142/edit) at the bottom of your question to paste the link.

Comment: Done. Just added it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like enabling Split Impulse in the Rigid Body World tab under the Scene tab just solved this issue. Increasing the Steps Per Second to 300 almost solves the bouncing 100%.

Comment: For me increasing Steps per second to 300 just made it more bouncy